# Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 32)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lstm

How can i edit this code so that I do not get the error in the title
MAX_FEATURES = 200000

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_FEATURES+1, 32))
/* Bidirectional LSTM Layer

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32,activation='tanh')))
/* Feature extractor Fully connected layers

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
/* Final layer 

model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))

input_text = vectorizer(`your text u freaking suck! I am going to hit you`)
res = model.predict(input_text)
```

`I am expecting the model to detect if input text is toxic or not`